# Caching on gitlab-ci isn't working when using Kubernetes cluster

Tags: caching, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When using gitlab-ci on a java+maven project; the maven artifacts are not cached. They are getting downloaded every-time.

I have deployed the gitlab-runner as kubernetes.

And the build time logs show

```
Creating cache edu-erp...
.m2/repository/: found 761 matching files          
No URL provided, cache will be not uploaded to shared cache server. Cache will be stored only locally.
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: maven:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmaven.repo.local=./.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    - ./.m2/repository
  # keep cache across branch
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"


stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  cache:
    key: edu-erp
    paths:
      - .m2/repository/
  script:
    - "mvn clean compile $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/

test:
  stage: test
  cache:
    key: edu-erp
  script:
    - "mvn test $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS"
```

The cache should be available across builds.

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741050/how-to-add-persistent-volume-for-maven-in-gitlab-with-kubernetes-runner/55748306#55748306

Comment: In my case, i have a shared runner environment for the entire suite of applications. i.e. Multiple projects use the same application. Heck even snapshot environment would be available.

So was looking for a feature branch wise cache.

Comment: after some research, found that minio cache server is an option. Does gitlab provide any on their own?