# Bind docker socket with a Kubernetes runner and share volume

Tags: gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using gitlab runner install with Helm and running on Google Cloud Kubernetes engine.

Here my runner configuration inside my values.yaml file :

```
runners:
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        image = "ubuntu:16.04"
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
          name = "docker-sock"
          mount_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
          host_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
```

When i launch a build where i share volume with the host, i receive this error :

```
ERROR: for c2abac41f403_******_haproxy_1  Cannot start service haproxy: error while creating mount source path '/builds/****/****/docker/test/haproxy.cfg': mkdir /builds: read-only file system
```

So i decide to add a volume pvc to my runner configuration

```
...
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.pvc]]
          name = "runner-claim"
          mount_path = "/builds"
...
```

But i receive this error :

```
Pod "runner-7vyyjqpv-project-8275433-concurrent-0dhn9h" is invalid: [spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[2].mountPath: Invalid value: "/builds": must be unique, spec.containers[1].volumeMounts[2].mountPath: Invalid value: "/builds": must be unique]
```

My goal is to use docker socket instead of docker in docker to have better performance.

Could you help me.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I would give a try with the solution from @viniciusxyz that was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066917/what-is-the-correct-way-to-mount-a-hostpah-volume-with-gitlab-runner). Seems that he was facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks but It doesn't help me :(

Comment: I would suggest to move this question to gitlab-ci-runner specific for more visibility since it seems that this is not a GKE issue but a specific for gitlab-ci  config.